# Unexpected output in variadic template C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I wrote a very simple code to add numbers in pair using variadic templates.
The expected output for the given test case should be 6 but i see 3. I also tried debugging but nothing looks wrong. Why is the output 3 but not 6?

```
template<typename T>
bool pairwise_sum(const T&first, const T&second) 
{
    return (first + second); 
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T pairwise_sum(const T&first, const T&second, Args... args)
{
    return (first + second) + pairwise_sum(args...);
}

void test()
{
    auto sumInPair = pairwise_sum(1, 1, 2, 2);
}
```

Also another question i have is since all the code is generated at compile time. Will the operator precedence matter? For e.g. if the function was something like :

```
template<typename T>
bool pairwise_sum_10fold(const T&first, const T&second) 
{
    return 10 * ( (first + second));
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T pairwise_sum_10fold(const T&first, const T&second, Args... args)
{
    return 10 * (first + second) + pairwise_sum_10fold(args...);
}
```

In this case does it matter whether i put return value in parenthesis as * has greater precedence than +?

P.S. I am using VS 2017 compiler.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: pairwise_sum returning bool?

Comment: thank you. I totally missed that. :(. Can you please answer my other question about the precedence?

Comment: @user888270 Those are two separate questions and should be split into two questions.

Comment: The 2nd set of parenthesis is unneeded, `10 * (first + second)` is enough. omitting all parenthesis would change the meaning: `10 * first + second` == `(10 * first) + second`.

Comment: how can compiler know what ordering the operators has to be in while expanding the variadic?

Comment: @user888270: I don't get your confusion :-/ There are function, not MACRO, so `pairwise_sum_10fold(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` would be `10 * (1 + 2) + pairwise_sum_10fold(3, 4, 5, 6)` as regular functions. You cannot have something like `5 * args + ...` which indeed would be problematic. but you might use `((5 * args) + ...)` or `5 * (args + ...)` (requires C++17).